# How to search for a folder using text in folder.description?

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to find an Outlook folder using folder.description value.

In folder.description I have more than one value. The code should take only one.

```vb
Private Sub CLemailbackupsaved_Click()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olItem As Object
    Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim intx As Long
    'Dim reportid As String
    
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFldr = olNS.Folders("a@a.com")
    Set olFldr = olFldr.Folders("Inbox")
    Debug.Print olFldr.Name
    For intx = 1 To olFldr.Folders.Count
        If olFldr.Folders.Item(intx).Description = "* MR090 *" Then
            Set objfolder = olFldr.Folders.Item(intx)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
   
    Debug.Print objfolder.Name

    Set olNS = Nothing
    Set objfolder = Nothing
    Set olFldr = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Folder.description example value:
MR091 MR090

Comment: `If InStr(olFldr.Folders.Item(intx).Description, "MR090") > 0 Then`